# set redirects and rewrites but router missed custom subpath

Tags: next.js, next-i18next

**next.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    locales: ['en', 'ko', 'ar'],
  },
  async redirects() {
    return [{
      source: '/ko',
      destination: '/myCustomKo',
      permanent: true,
      locale: false,
     }]
  },
  async rewrites() {
    return {
      afterFiles: [{
        source: '/myCustomKo',
        destination: '/ko',
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to use my `/ko` route to `/myCustomKo`.

It works only when it is loaded first. I can see `/myCustomKo` instead of `/ko`.

and I move route with `<Link href="/">root</Link>`, my subpath is gone. I expect it still be `/myCustomKo` not `/`.

when I try this process in `/en`, everything is perfect. I clicked `<Link />`, it still be `/en`.

How can I keep my custom subpath?

**Summary**

When my subpath is `/en`, I can route anywhere with `/en`.

When my subpath is `/ar`, I can also route anywhere with `/ar`.

But when my subpath is `/myCustomKo`, my router miss `/myCustomKo` subpath.